# Rss feed not showing from all the tables

Tags: javascript, php, rss

I am using this rss.php file for rss feed but the problem is that it shows feed from just 2 tables not all the 4.Where is the problem?Feed is coming from famous people and econmicsandpolitics table only.

```
<?php
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wg','root','', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}


$pdo = connect();
$myarray = array('scienceandtechnology','economicsandpolitics','famouspeople','yetosbkistoryhe');
$key = array_rand($myarray);
$table= $myarray[$key];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table."";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rs_post = $query->fetchAll();

// The XML structure
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$data .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$data .= '<channel>';
$data .= '<title>google</title>';
$data .= '<link>http://www.google.com</link>';
$data .= '<description>io</description>';
foreach ($rs_post as $row) {
    $data .= '<item>';
    $data .= '<title>'.$row['title'].'</title>';
    $data .= '<link>'.$row['content'].'</link>';
    $data .= '<description>'.$row['summary'].'</description>';
    $data .= '</item>';
}
$data .= '</channel>';
$data .= '</rss> ';

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are here using it statically from table names i have almost same kind of problem but in my case the table name is also dynamic So use it according to your relevance

```
$sql = mysql_query("select name from sections order by rand()");
$datadisplay = array();

while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $section=$row['name'];
    $sqldata = mysql_query("select title,summary from ".$section." order by ID limit 2");
    while ($rowdata= mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata)){
        $datadisplay[] = $rowdata;
    }
}
```

so here what i am doing is i fetching table names from sections and after that using those table names to fetch data from table and then storing that data into another array which then can be used to get rss data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct it may help you ,

```
$pdo = connect();
$myarray =  array('scienceandtechnology','economicsandpolitics','famouspeople','yetosbkistoryhe');

foreach ($myarray as $table) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table."";
   $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $rs_post = $query->fetchAll();   
   foreach ($rs_post as $post) {
        // echo something
   }             
}
```

Comment: now after using this it shows feed from only one table@Vishnu R Nair

Comment: Just echo $table . so you can get the table names